# How does language change affects URL

Tags: url, localization, dns

When I view sites in other languages, their URLs either change to http://ru.wikipedia.org for example or http://somesite.com/ru/.

I think in first example they use third-level domain, in the second they use root subdirectory (folder).

So I am interested: is there any difference? how do these structures work and why do they exist?

Answer (score 0):

`ru.wikipedia.org` - The 'ru' here is a subdomain. This acts as a redirect to another location. In most cases this is a subdirectory on the site, but it is also used to redirect to any other URL.

`somesite.com/ru/` - The 'ru' here is usually a subdirectory, but it can also be a [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services). Twitter is a good example of a RESTful web service (a subdirectory doesn't exist for each user, but the content is dynamically created at runtime).

Subdomains such as `ru.wikipedia.org` are usually used for subsites - such as the Russian version of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I remember three reasons why I went away from the third-level domain solution:

1. You have to explicitly take care about **cookies**. They have to be set for the top-level domain to be shared between all domains.
2. Also you have to ensure that you are referencing all assets (images, css, javascript) absolutely to leverage **browser caching**.
3. It's just guessing (I'm not an expert in this area) but you are also influencing search engine relevancy as the third-level domains won't count in the second level domain that much.